# Oracle - Partial Delete on Junction Table

Tags: oracle

I want to perform multiple deletes on a junction table in one request/query. Complexity is the data I want to delete don't share the same pattern.

Example :
I have 3 tables, **Tab1 Tab2 and TabJct3**. TabJct3 is the junction table of Tab1/Tab2. Simple auto inc for the ID of Tab1/Tab2. TabJct3 has 2 ID, one for each "junctionned" table. Tab1Id and Tab2Id

Records are :

Tab1 : T1R1

Tab2 : T2R1, T2R2, T2R3

TabJct3 : [T1R1, T2R1], [T1R1, T2R2], [T1R1, T2R3]

Suppose I want to delete these records from TabJct3 : [T1R1, T2R1], [T1R1, T2R2] (but not [T1R1, T2R3]).

An example of query would be (naive) :

`DELETE FROM TabJct3 WHERE (SELECT Tab1Id, Tab2Id FROM TabJct3 WHERE Tab1Id = 'T1R1' AND Tab2Id = 'T2R1') AND (SELECT Tab1Id, Tab2Id FROM TabJct3 WHERE Tab1Id = 'T1R1' AND Tab2Id = 'T2R2')`

I want to avoid specific subselects, because it does the same amount of requests as there are records to delete.

Is there any alternative to one subselect per record?

Comment: Do you want to delete from the link table all rows with `key 1` from `TAB1` but *not* with `key 3` from `TAB2` - if so, you should try it this way.

Comment: You said: "Suppose I want to delete [T1R1, T2R1], [T1R1, T2R2], and I want to keep [T1R1, T2R3]." That's table `TabJct3`, right? Why are you deleting from `Tab1`, then? In other words: I don't understand the question. If possible, provide sample data that show what you have and what you'd want to get as a result.

Comment: I edited my question to supply added info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are not using values directly in the `where` clause instead of subqueries as following:

```
DELETE FROM TabJct3 
WHERE (Tab1Id, Tab2Id) IN 
(('T1R1', 'T2R1'),('T1R1','T2R2'));
```

Or

```
DELETE FROM TabJct3 
WHERE Tab1Id = 'T1R1'
  AND Tab2Id IN ('T2R1','T2R2');
```

Cheers!!